# Xcode 10 does not index newly created class

Tags: objective-c, xcode10

Everytime i create a new `Cocoa Touch Class`. Xcode does not index it. There is no syntax highlighting or auto-completion suggestions for newly created class.
I tried building/running the project. Project run successfully but still not indexing for that file.

I can get it work by quitting and relaunching Xcode but thats too annoying.
Does anyone had the same problem or any suggestions to fix this :(

Comment: yeah i faced that problem .you tried almost all the method .. try shut down your system and on again .. some times that will be work

Comment: This is what we are doing - "Close/Reopen" project :0

Answer (score 2):

Usually (though not always) deleting your `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*` and restarting Xcode helps.

Comment: that is a work around like many others, not a proper solution where e.g you can do CMD + B to build there is nothing like that for reindexing, at least not that I know of